# How to add my code to window focus function

Tags: javascript, browser

My website has a download page, I created a count down in the page and I need to add it to window focus function. Here's my code:

```js
<script>
    var content = document.getElementById("container");
    content.style.display = "none";

    setTimeout(function(){
        content.style.display = "block";
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Is your code actually like this, with `&quot;` everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `window.addEventListener` to run this piece of code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    let downloadTimeout;

    // Will be executed every time the window is focused
    window.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        const content = document.getElementById("container");
        content.style.display = "none";

        downloadTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            content.style.display = "block";
        }, 10000);
    });

    // Will be executed every time the window is blurred
    window.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        if (downloadTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(downloadTimeout);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yanick I added this but the download button always appears.